# Request completion handler fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value exception

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, in-app-purchase, swift4

I've implemented In-App-Purchase in my ios app. Here I've used `RequestCompletionHandler` at `SKProductsRequestDelegate` method as shown below. Some times app getting crash because `nil` value. What is wrong in my code?

`completionHandler` is declared as: `fileprivate var completionHandler: RequestCompletionHandler!`

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse!) {

print("Successfully loaded list of products..")
productsRequest = nil
    if response.products.count > 0 {
        if let skProducts = response.products as? [SKProduct] {
            for product in skProducts {
                print("found product: \(product.productIdentifier), \(product.localizedTitle), \(product.price.floatValue)")
            }
            completionHandler(true, skProducts as NSArray)  //unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value exception getting in this line
            completionHandler = nil
        }
    }
}
```

See the screenshot below for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

If completion handler can be `nil` I recommend to either use `if let`, or in your case optional method call:

```
completionHandler?(true, skProducts as NSArray)
```

Since you used implicitly unwrapped optional (you used `!` in `completionHandler` declaration), line `completionHandler(true, skProducts as NSArray)` is the same as `completionHandler!(true, skProducts as NSArray)` which ignores the possibility that `completionHandler` might be `nil` and tries to execute it. If `completionHandler` is `nil`, it crashes. Unless you can be 100% sure that it will never be `nil`, never use implicit unwrap.

Moreover, I would strongly recommend not to use implicitly unwrapped types as property types, unless you have a really good reason for doing so. In this case obviously the `completionHandler` can be `nil`. Rather change the declaration to an optional:

```
fileprivate var completionHandler: RequestCompletionHandler?
```

Comment: It depends. It's fine if it is a bug when it's nil, you will be told at runtime. As the OP was. Now if someone doesn't know the difference between ? and !, that's tough.

Answer (score 0):

You declared completionHandler as RequestCompletionHandler!

That means you are telling the compiler: "completionHandler could be nil, but I'm absolutely one hundred percent sure it isn't whenever I use it, so if I use it while it is nil, then please do me a favour and crash the application".

And that's exactly what the compiler is doing. You shouldn't be calling completionHandler when it's nil. Either you forgot to set it, or it is intentional that it isn't set (but that is very very very unlikely), then you need to check that it is nil.